# ngb popover not rendering html encoding

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, html-encode

I need to render some text inside ngbPopover, I am able to do that. 
The problem here is I need a line breaks between text.

I tried using <br>, \n, \u000A nothings works for me <br> getting displayed as is and for \n and \u000A I see no effect on screen.

following is my code for reference.

html

```html
<ng-template #subCoveragePopup>
   <div class="sub-coverage-tooltip">
      <div class="details">
        <div *ngFor="let subCov of getSubCoverageDescription(quoteCoverage.coverage)">
          <div class="title">{{subCov.code}}</div>
          <div class="">{{subCov.name}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</ng-template>
```

inside `subCov.name` I get the following text through angular ->

> Testing: this is line 1\u000A This is line 2

OR

> Testing: this is line \n This is line 2

OR

> Testing: this is line <BR>
> This is line 2

With all three options, I am not able to display the line break. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Did you tried using css for the same div : style="white-space: pre;" ?

Comment: Thank  you @Bozhinovski it worked after adding the style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add css style to the same div :

```html
<ng-template #subCoveragePopup>
   <div class="sub-coverage-tooltip">
      <div class="details">
        <div *ngFor="let subCov of getSubCoverageDescription(quoteCoverage.coverage)">
          <div class="title">{{subCov.code}}</div>
          <div class="splitLine">{{subCov.name}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</ng-template>
```

```css
.splitLine {
    style="white-space: pre;"
}
```

Comment: just a small addition to this, if you want longer lines to be wrapped use "white-space: pre-line"